# How to increase the figsize in such a way that the figure remains of the size and labels in x-axis should appear fully instead of getting cut?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, figure, figsize

[image]

If I am increasing the figsize only in the x-axis then the whole figure is getting enlarged and is not looking good. I want to keep the figure same but labels should fully appear at the rotation of 90 degrees. Rotating xlabels is also not happening properly.

Comment: Welcome to SO. First of all, do not paste links to images. Instead, include the image in your question. Secondly, share data and code of what you have tried so far. This increases the chance (and willingness) for the community to help you.

Comment: Did you try `plt.tight_layout()` at the end?

Comment: @SergedeGossondeVarennes Okay, will take care of these things from the next time.

Comment: @JohanC This worked, I was not using it earlier.

Comment: @SergedeGossondeVarennes  Good remarks. But take care that new users aren't allowed yet to post inline images (because too many want to post code, data or error messages as images instead of as text). Once they have gained some reputation, this limitation is removed. Meanwhile, more experienced users can edit the post to inline the images and help with other formatting issues.